# Getting the tokens from NSTokenField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I can get the value of a NSTokenField by doing `[NSTokenField stringValue]` but this does not return the tokens individually. What I'm trying to get is the token fields in an array i.e `['token', 'token2']`.

I'm a bit ignorant when it comes to Cocoa/Objective-c so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing something obvious.

NSTokenField doesn't respond to `count` so I'm not sure if it's even possible to get the tokens back.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there a consistent separator character in the result of `stringValue`? Just use [`componentsSeparatedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-componentsSeparatedByString_).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/GetSetTokenFields/GetSetTokenFields.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006555-CH9-SW2):

> To retrieve the objects represented by the tokens in a token field, send the token field an [`objectValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/objectValue) message. Although this method is declared by `NSControl`, `NSTokenField` implements it to return an array of represented objects. If the token field simply contains a series of strings, `objectValue` returns an array of strings. To set the represented objects of a token field, use the [`setObjectValue:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/setObjectValue:) method, passing in an array of represented objects. If these objects aren’t strings, `NSTokenField` then queries its delegate for the display strings to use for each token.

Comment: Great!
It would be great if there was a tokens @property of the type NSArray, or at least the same description above on the Class reference page of the NSTokenField...
Thanks for your answer